# What happens when you multiply a matrix with purely imaginary eigenvalues with a vector?

Tags: complex-numbers

I've read in my book that if the eigenvalues of a square matrix $\mathbf{A}$ are $\pm i\beta$, then

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{w} = i\beta\mathbf{w}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{w}$  is a nonzero complex vector

How does this work? I've found this not to be the case.

For example:

\begin{eqnarray}
\left[ \begin{array}{cC}
0+3i & 0 \\
0 & 0 - 3i
\end{array} \right]
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
1+i \\
2+i
\end{array} \right]
&=&
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
-3+3i \\ 3-6i
\end{array} \right] \\
%
&=& 3i
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
1+i \\
-2-i 
\end{array} \right] \neq 3i\mathbf{w}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the book has an awful mistake, you're misinterpreting what was written.  That's only the case where $\bf w$ is an eigenvector for eigenvalue $i\beta$.  What **exactly** does the book say?

Comment: In the context of Hopf bifurcations: Hopf points are characterised by a simple pair of purely imaginary eigenvalues $\pm i\beta$ of the Jacobian $\mathbf{f_y}(\mathbf{y_0}, \ \lambda_0)$. Hence, the equation $\mathbf{f_y}(\mathbf{y_0}, \ \lambda_0) \mathbf{w} = i \beta \mathbf{w}$ holds for a nonzero complex vector $\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{h} + i\mathbf{g}$.

Comment: So it's saying there is **some** such vector $\bf w$, namely an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $i\beta$.  It's not saying that's true for every $\bf w$.